# How to print the trained parameters of a classifier in TensorFlow

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I trained a model in TensorFlow, and saved it on disk.
Now I want to load it from checkpoint and print the trained parameters.
Something like:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=hidden_units,
    warm_start_from=checkpoint_path)

print(parameters(classifier))
```

How do I do that?
I'm using tf version 1.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use these two methods `get_variable_names()` and `get_variable_value()` to retrieve the parameters in your classifier.

```py
params = classifier.get_variable_names()
for p in params:
    print(p, classifier.get_variable_value(p))
```